Vulkan version to play xbox 360 games via Xenia on Linux and VM
I need your experiences to solve the following situation.
I copied one of my xbox360's game : Need for Speed Hot Pursuit, in order to play it on my PC with Xenia emulator. Note that NFS Hot Pursuit is compatible with xenia-canary.
I used 2 different platforms with different conditions:

On Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (64bits architecture), using Lutris 0.5.17 and Wine 9.0 to launch xenia-canary.exe. xenia-canary.config.toml file is configured on gpu = "vulkan". GPU is GeForce GTX 1060 6GB.
On Windows 10  Professionnal 21H2 through a virtual machine (Oracle VM VirtualBox) without intermediate to launch xenia-canary.exe. xenia-canary.config.toml file is configured on gpu = "any". GPU is VirtualBox Graphics Adapter (WDDM) 7.0.10.8379.

Results:

On Ubuntu the title bar indicates [45410903 v10.0] NFS Hot Pursuit <Vulkan - FBO - HEAVILY INCOMPLETE, early development>. The game starts but very slowly and crashes in the following seconds. Vulkan is installed : vulkaninfo command returns Vulkan Instance Version: 1.2.131.
On Windows 10 VM the title bar indicates [45410903 v10.0] NFS Hot Pursuit <Direct3D 12 - RTV/DSV>`. The game does not start at all.

So, I guess Vulkan is essential to make it run with acceptable performances. Then, many questions come to my mind:

Is it possible to use Vulkan in Windows while the GPU is only "architectural" ?
In Ubuntu, considering I use Lutris* and Wine as intermediate layers, should I install a Vulkan version for Windows platform through something like Winetricks or update my Vulkan version in my Ubuntu OS ?

*In Lutris configurations, Configure > Execution options > Graphics it tells Warning Your NVIDIA driver is outdated. You are currently running driver 470.256.02 which does not fully support all features for Vulkan and DXVK games.

What do you mean with "the GPU is only "architectural""?

@Joachim I mean it is not a physical hardware. As a proxy server is not a physical hardware server, that's "architectural". Maybe it is more appropriated I use the term "virtual" like virtual machine, actually.

From experience, playing games in a VM is a terrible experience. It may work, if you're determined and lucky, but then the performance may be awful and the controls may be laggy. You'd have a much easier time playing directly on Windows and using Linux via a VM or WSL instead. In my case, I couldn't even get Age of Mythology (a 2002 game) to run with decent performace on a Windows XP VM and on a 4K high end PC from 2018 running Windows 10. Your case is likely to be worse. You're trying to emulate a console from 2005 in a VM. Even if it works, it probably won't be fun.

@Nolonar Alright. So I must continue on Ubuntu track. I won't install Windows on my PC, even in dual boot because many people knew Ubuntu's boot issues due to Windows.

But you have a GeForce GTX 1060 in this setup, right?

@Joachim Right. This is my physical GPU.

Sorry if I'm being dim here, but then why would you use Vulkan explicitly using a virtual GPU while you have a capable physical GPU?

@Joachim because it is known Xenia could work a lot better with Vulkan. Then in my case, my main OS is Ubuntu, and Xenia is not made for Ubuntu but for Windows (an OS I hate and dual boot is risky because Windows may corrupt Linux based OS to boot), so I use Lutris + Wine to run Xenia on Ubuntu. So if my game isn't running there are two more parameters to check (Lutris and Wine), while on Windows it's only a matter of GPU driver, because no Lutris and no Wine.

But Vulkan is just an alternative API to DirectX, so my question is more about why you want to use Vulkan with a virtual GPU when you have a capable dedicated GPU, which would logically boost performance.

@Joachim The virtual GPU is an implementation of Oracle VM Virtual Box, that's not my choice. Moreover using DirectX doesn't work at all.

@Nolonar Sorry to ask you again. By pure curiosity, the VM you used was with a bare-metal hypervisor or an hosted hypervisor?

@AvyWam, it was a hosted hypervisor (VirtualBox on Windows). The CPU was an i7 3770K. This was in 2013, though, so maybe the situation has improved in the past decade?

@Nolonar Thank you for your answer. For VirtualBox that is a hosted hypervisor, I did try and think it has not change that much. Maybe with WMware and other bare-metal hypervisor it could be very different (in improvement) because the usage of hardware components is different. I will try when I will find the time. Thank you again.
